# Angular 5 the class property is automatically changing

Tags: angular

I have a scenario where I need to discard changes in the list of questions for that purpose I am saving the initial value to a variable named 'backupQuestions' and making changes to the original variable named 'questions'. The problem is whenever the value of 'questions' is changing the ''backupQuestions' is also getting updated even though I am not the updating the value of 'backupQuestions'.

```
getQuestionsForSection() {
this.questionService.getQuestions(formId, sectionId, false).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res.code ===
        200 && res.isSuccess === true && res.data['questions']) {
        console.log("Questions: ", res.data['questions']);
        this.questions = res.data['questions']; //this is the original variable
        this.questionsBackup = res.data['questions']; //this is the duplicate variable
       } else { this.toastr.show(res.message, "
            error "); } }, (err) => { this.toastr.show(err.error.message, "
            error "); }); }
```

when I am trying to discard the changes I am reassigning the 'questionsBackup' to 'questions' but values in both the variables are same.

I don't know why is this happening, I have come across similar cases quite a few times. Is this something because of angular's architecture?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like questions is array. You should create a copy of array, because original and backup have same ref in your example:

```
 this.questionsBackup = res.data['questions'].slice();
```

If items in questions array are objrcts, you should create their copies as well:

```
 this.questionsBackup =res.data['questions'].map((item=>Object.assign({}, item))
```

Comment: Its working. Thanks its working :). I will keep in mind that   Objects does not point to the value but  the ref. Thanks a lot.